# How to Create generic method to return multiple list in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, list, entity-framework, generic-list

i have create a generic method that's return a single list. but i need to pass multiple list and it will return multiple list result set in mvc using entity framework.

```
public void ExecuteList<T>(out List<T> obj, string sql, params object[] parameters) where T : class
    {
        using (var db = _context)
        {
            var cmd = db.Database.Connection.CreateCommand();
            cmd.CommandText = sql;
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Parameters.AddRange(parameters);
            try
            {
                db.Database.Connection.Open();
                using (var reder = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    obj = ((IObjectContextAdapter)db).ObjectContext.Translate<T>(reder).ToList();

                }
            }
            finally
            {
                db.Database.Connection.Close();
                cmd.Dispose();
            }
        }
    }
```

when i call this method in my controller it will give me a single list.

```
   public ActionResult Index()
    { 
        List<SqlParameter> parameterList = new List<SqlParameter>();
        parameterList.Add(new SqlParameter("@pageNo", 1));
        parameterList.Add(new SqlParameter("@pageSize", 5));            
        SqlParameter[] parameters = parameterList.ToArray();
        List<PostModel> PostModel = new List<PostModel>();           
        Uow.ExecuteList<PostModel>(out PostModel, "[dbo].[sp_getdata]", parameters);  
        return View();
    }
```

but i need to pass multiple list and it will give me multiple list result.

```
           List<SqlParameter> parameterList = new List<SqlParameter>();
        parameterList.Add(new SqlParameter("@pageNo", 1));
        parameterList.Add(new SqlParameter("@pageSize", 5)); 
        SqlParameter[] parameters = parameterList.ToArray();
        List<PostModel> PostModel = new List<PostModel>();
        List<Tag> Tag = new List<Tag>();
        Uow.ExecuteList<PostModel,Tag>(out PostModel, out Tag, "[dbo].[sp_Getdata]", parameters);
```

please help me how to complete above requirement.

Comment: This is very unclear, please spend a little time explaining your needs and desires in more detail (**and not in comments**) edit the question

Answer (score 0):

You can use value tuple to do it.

```
 (ReturnType1 returnName1, ReturnType2 returnName2) Foo<T>(argument...)
```

For example

```
(T postModel, U tag) ExecuteList<T, U>(argument...)
{
      // the code
      return (postModel, tag);
}
```

The generic method can use some type just as the code using `<T, U>` and the T and U are two types.

Comment: Above code is not useful from me. I want to pass multiple list with out parameter but want to use optional parameter and also <t> type is optional.

ExecuteList<T,T1>(out List<T> obj, out List<T1> obj1,  string sql, params object[] parameters) where T : class

Above code <T,T1> and (out List<T> obj, out List<T1> obj1) both should be optional.

Please help me to solve my issue.